# Loop optimisation while scanning huge exponential values

Tags: java, loops, optimization

I am trying to run a code where the user can input a value as large as 10^18 and I have to scan each value from 1 to 10^18 so as to perform some operations on them. The code is not optimized. I tried loop unrolling but still it won't work. Can someone tell that what can be the best way to reduce the time complexity of this program?

Comment: If your operation takes 1 nanosecond, performing it on 10^18 numbers will take 31 years.

Comment: There is insufficient information in your question to make suggestions that are going to help.  You need an algorithmic optimization ... that means that you don't have to scan the entire range.  Loop optimization most likely won't make a noticeable difference.  Using threads would help, but you only get *at most* P-times speed up where P is the number of available processors.  And that isn't enough to give you a practical solution.

Comment: If you had (exclusive) access to a large HPC system, you might be able to get answers a few tens of thousand times faster.  But I doubt that you do.  (People don't get to use such expensive systems unless they first demonstrate that they know what they are doing, and that their task is sufficiently important ...)

Comment: There is no way whatsoever that operating over 10^18 values will be doable in a reasonable amount of time.  You have to do something smarter than checking every value, and you haven't told us enough about the problem for us to help you do that.